# Яка семантика та етимологія фрази "холєра"?

Tags: етимологія, ненормативна-лексика

Цікавить фраза **"от холєра!"** або ж її варіант **"холєра ясна!"**. 
На сайті [Суто українська лайка (як лаялися наші бабусі :))](http://maidan.org.ua/arch/mova/1120125007.html) знайшла лише згадку, що існують "ідіоми "холєра ясна", "щоб ти з бика впав", вираз "а жеби тебе..."та ін."
У [Словнику української мови](http://sum.in.ua/s/kholera) є тільки стаття про лексему "холера", зокрема і подано фразу "холера з ним" - "уживається для вираження мимовільної згоди на що-небудь, втрати інтересу до чого-небудь, як знак того, що щось можна залишити поза увагою". Очевидно, що про хворобу тут не йдеться, але все ж мене цікавить власне етимологія фрази, а також і семантика як така.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На мою думку вказані Вами значення слів «холера»/«холєра» походять якраз від хвороби. «Холера з ним» ≈ «[біс](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=4540&page=172) із ним» ≈ «хай йому [грець](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=20062&page=679)» ≈ «хай воно сконає». У випадку «мимовільної згоди на що-небудь» це, мабуть, застосовується в бік перепон, що початково заважали погодитися, або можливих негативних наслідків чи самих думок про них.

Сполучення зі словом «ясна» мені менш зрозуміле. Можливо, «[ясний](http://sum.in.ua/s/jasnyj)» у значенні «очевидний», мовляв, «ну все, точно холера!» (менш імовірно — контамінація із «гори воно ясним полум'ям»).

[«Етимологічний словник української мови» в 7 томах](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) при роз'ясненні ліній походження не надає жодних інших трактовок слова «холера» окрім «хвороба» і «рослина Xanthium spinosum», причому остання також пов'язується із хворобою.

Answer (score 1):

Щодо "Холєри ясної". 
Повна форма "Niech cię jasna cholera weźmie!" (Хай тебе холера ясна візьме), потім залишилось тільки "Холера ясна" (cholera jasna).
"Jasna" польською значить "світла", думаю, є натяк на прозорість екскрементів :) - смертельна холерна діарея , якраз така.

Comment: **Дуже добре!** Чи не могли б Ви додати якись приклад чи словник, де застосовується словосполучення «jasna cholera weźmie»? Просто щоб у читачів не було сумнівів, що так і є.

Comment: Щодо «прозорість екскрементів… смертельна холерна діярея» — звучить логічно. Але ж іще є вирази «jasny gwint», «jasna Anielka» («do jasnej Anielki»), «do jasnej ciasnej» — чому в них _jasny_? Чи це просто евфемізми, що походять від «cholera jasna»?

Comment: «свіла» — це, напевно, одрук? Малося на увазі «свіТла»?

Comment: Польська пісенька:
Teraz jest wojna,
Kto nie handluje, nie zbiera.
Zabrali rombankę,
Słoninę, kaszankę,
Niech weźmie ich jasna cholera!

Comment: @Sasha Польська пісенька: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guZQgTdS3Yc